# Clear Select Material UI with React State

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, spfx

I´m tying to clear all Criteria's from some controls using `state` but having problems with the Select Material UI

In the costructor

```
this.HandleclearFiters = this.HandleclearFiters.bind(this);
```

The Clear Handler for the Button

```
 HandleclearFiters() {
    this.setState({
      startEmission: "",
      endEmission: "",
      startValidity: "",
      endValidity: "",
      participantFirstName: "",
      participantLastName: "",
      paticipantCertNumber: "",
      selectYesNo: "",
      selectLevel: ""
    });
  }
```

This works in a `<TextField`

```
<TextField id="txtStartEmission" 
value={this.state.startEmission} 
onChange={e => this.setState({ startEmission: e.target.value })}
```

This will not work on a `<Select`

So I tried this workaround, not working also

```
<Select
labelId="selPrintedLabel"
id="selPrinted"
label="Printed"
fullWidth={true}
variant="outlined"
defaultValue={this.state.selectYesNo}
onChange={e => this.setState({ selectYesNo: typeof e.target.value === 'string' ? e.target.value : '' })}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Isn't this because you're using defaultValue, not value?

Comment: `defaultValue` doesnt update when the variable changes, is the first one to be set. use `value` instead

Comment: There should also be an option in the `select` that has `''` as the value.

Comment: I had to implement ```value``` and ```defaultvalue``` in order to work thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `value` prop on the Select:
`value={this.state.selectYesNo}`

Material UI Select API doc here: https://mui.com/api/select/

Comment: Yep, thanks, imlemented ```value``` and ```defaultvalue``` it works now cool

Answer (score 1):

You can clear icon in the select like this

```
  IconComponent={
              field.value.length > 1
                ? () => (
                    <IconButton
                      size="small"
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        field.onChange("");
                      }}
                    >
                      <MdClear />
                    </IconButton>
                  )
                : undefined
            }
```